# Error #1064 while trying to create a trigger after insert

Tags: mysql, triggers

I'm working on this trigger definition:

```
DECLARE var_count INT;
SELECT COUNT(1) INTO var_count FROM isrl_config;
IF var_count == 1
    UPDATE isrl_config SET last_retention_number = NEW.id;
END IF;
```

But I get `#1064` error and don't know why. See the attached image for more info, what is wrong?[image]

**2nd result after update**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Surround it with `BEGIN ... END`

```
BEGIN
    DECLARE var_count INT;
    SELECT COUNT(1) INTO var_count FROM isrl_config;
    IF var_count = 1 THEN
        UPDATE isrl_config SET last_retention_number = NEW.id;
    END IF;
END
```

From the [manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/declare.html):

> DECLARE is permitted only inside a BEGIN ... END compound statement and must be at its start, before any other statements.

And [also](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/if.html):

```
IF search_condition THEN statement_list
    [ELSEIF search_condition THEN statement_list] ...
    [ELSE statement_list]
END IF
```

Comment: I did as you suggest but now the error changed as second image show in main post

Comment: The if-statement is somewhat different. Use a single `=` (just like in a normal query) and `THEN`. I've updated my answer.